# Application of Wilks' theorem to poisson data

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, likelihood-ratio

My parametrized astrophysical model predicts a mean bin count $e_i(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_p)$ for each of $N$ non-overlapping energy regions. For a set of observed counts $k_i$ the joint likelihood is given by

$$P(k_1,\ldots,k_N,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_p)=\prod_{i=1}^N \frac{e_i^{k_i}e^{-e_i}}{k_i!}$$

where the $\theta $ dependence is suppressed on the right.
In [Cash, 1979](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1979ApJ...228..939C) it's claimed that the log-likelihood statistic will be $\chi^2$ distributed as $N\rightarrow \infty$, and supposedly this is due to [Wilks'](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2957648) theorem. However the $k^i$ are not drawn from a single distribution $f$ as in Wilks' equation (1):

$$ P'=\prod_{i=1}^N f(k_i,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_p).$$ It seems like the distribution $f$ would also have to depend on the bin index in order for Wilks' result to be applicable. Have I misunderstood something?